# Installation Link Breaks in Production - Shopify App

Tags: node.js, express, shopify

EDIT: I believe the issue is that `app.use(serveStatic(PROD_INDEX_PATH));` prevents the `app.use("/*",` middleware from running. I'm still working on a solution and any help would be appreciated!

My Shopify app breaks after deploying to Heroku but ONLY when clicking the provided "install" link.

For example, when I click "Install App", this is the URL that is generated: `https://shopify-app.herokuapp.com/?hmac=d61597ca3ea6ca74b8bd6ea8f8bcc812b4382fad6f15434c0158bc4c3ade519a&host=dXBsaWZ0ZWQtY29tbWVyY2UtZGV2Lm15c2hvcGlmeS5jb20vYWRtaW4&shop=dev.myshopify.com&timestamp=1657326911`

Which skips that auth process and takes me to "This page does not exist."

So the flow is: "Click Install App" => "This page does not exist"

However, if I manually click the auth link: `https://shopify-app.herokuapp.com/api/auth?shop=dev.myshopify.com`, the app successfully completes the auth process and works without any issues.

I'm using the standard server code scaffolded from the [Shopify CLI](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-template-node).

Commenting out this section in production allows the app to partially function:

```
  if (isProd) {
    const compression = await import("compression").then(
      ({ default: fn }) => fn
    );
    const serveStatic = await import("serve-static").then(
      ({ default: fn }) => fn
    );
    app.use(compression());
    app.use(serveStatic(PROD_INDEX_PATH));
  }
```

Once the code is commented out, the generated install link is of the format: https://shopify-app.herokuapp.com/api/auth?shop=dev.myshopify.com. However, functionality throughout the app breaks upon clicking the install button.

The new flow is: "Click Install App" => "Begin Auth flow" => "Accept requested scopes" => "App breaks"

So essentially, the code snippet `if(isProd)` breaks the installation link while removing it breaks the rest of the app's functionality.

More specifically, the `app.use(serveStatic(PROD_INDEX_PATH));` snippet.

Really scratching my head on this one. Any ideas what's going on?

This is my server:

```
const USE_ONLINE_TOKENS = true;
const TOP_LEVEL_OAUTH_COOKIE = "shopify_top_level_oauth";

// @ts-ignore
const PORT = parseInt(process.env.BACKEND_PORT || process.env.PORT, 10);
const isTest = process.env.NODE_ENV === "test" || !!process.env.VITE_TEST_BUILD;

const versionFilePath = "./version.txt";
let templateVersion = "unknown";
if (fs.existsSync(versionFilePath)) {
  templateVersion = fs.readFileSync(versionFilePath, "utf8").trim();
}

// TODO: There should be provided by env vars
const DEV_INDEX_PATH = `${process.cwd()}/frontend/`;
const PROD_INDEX_PATH = `${process.cwd()}/frontend/dist/`;

const DB_PATH = `${process.cwd()}/database.sqlite`;

Shopify.Context.initialize({
  // @ts-ignore
  API_KEY: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
  // @ts-ignore
  API_SECRET_KEY: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_SECRET,
  // @ts-ignore
  SCOPES: process.env.SCOPES.split(","),
  // @ts-ignore
  HOST_NAME: process.env.HOST.replace(/https?:\/\//, ""),
  // @ts-ignore
  HOST_SCHEME: process.env.HOST.split("://")[0],
  API_VERSION: ApiVersion.April22,
  IS_EMBEDDED_APP: true,
  // This should be replaced with your preferred storage strategy
  // SESSION_STORAGE: new Shopify.Session.SQLiteSessionStorage(DB_PATH),
  SESSION_STORAGE: new Shopify.Session.CustomSessionStorage(
    storeCallback,
    // @ts-ignore
    loadCallback,
    deleteCallback
  ),

  USER_AGENT_PREFIX: `Node App Template/${templateVersion}`,
});


const ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS = {};
Shopify.Webhooks.Registry.addHandler("APP_UNINSTALLED", {
  path: "/api/webhooks",
  webhookHandler: async (topic, shop, body) => {
    // @ts-ignore
    delete ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS[shop],
      //Delete unsubscribed shop and clean undefined entries

      console.log("APP UNINSTALLED");

    await pool.query(
      `DELETE FROM shop WHERE shop_url=$1 OR shop_url='undefined' OR shop_url='' OR shop_url IS NULL`,
      [shop]
    );
  },
});


setupGDPRWebHooks("/api/webhooks");

// export for test use only
export async function createServer(
  root = process.cwd(),
  isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
  billingSettings = BILLING_SETTINGS
) {
  const app = express();
  app.set("top-level-oauth-cookie", TOP_LEVEL_OAUTH_COOKIE);
  app.set("active-shopify-shops", ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS);
  app.set("use-online-tokens", USE_ONLINE_TOKENS);

  app.use(cookieParser(Shopify.Context.API_SECRET_KEY));


  applyAuthMiddleware(app, {
    billing: billingSettings,
  });

  app.post("/api/webhooks", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      await Shopify.Webhooks.Registry.process(req, res);
      console.log(`Webhook processed, returned status code 200`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Failed to process webhook: ${error}`);
      if (!res.headersSent) {
        res.status(500).send(error.message);
      }
    }
  });


  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  // All endpoints after this point will require an active session
  app.use(
    "/api/*",
    verifyRequest(app, {
      // @ts-ignore
      billing: billingSettings,
    })
  );

  //app.use("/api/test", test);
  app.use("/api/sort-options", sortOptions);
  app.use("/api/sort-logic", sortLogic);

  app.get("/api/products-count", async (req, res) => {
    const session = await Shopify.Utils.loadCurrentSession(req, res, true);
    const { Product } = await import(
      `@shopify/shopify-api/dist/rest-resources/${Shopify.Context.API_VERSION}/index.js`
    );

    const countData = await Product.count({ session });
    res.status(200).send(countData);
  });

  app.post("/api/graphql", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const response = await Shopify.Utils.graphqlProxy(req, res);
      res.status(200).send(response.body);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error.message);
    }
  });

  app.use(express.json());

  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const shop = req.query.shop;
    if (Shopify.Context.IS_EMBEDDED_APP && shop) {
      res.setHeader(
        "Content-Security-Policy",
        `frame-ancestors https://${shop} https://admin.shopify.com;`
      );
    } else {
      res.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", `frame-ancestors 'none';`);
    }
    next();
  });

  if (isProd) {
    const compression = await import("compression").then(
      ({ default: fn }) => fn
    );
    const serveStatic = await import("serve-static").then(
      ({ default: fn }) => fn
    );
    app.use(compression());
    app.use(serveStatic(PROD_INDEX_PATH));
    console.log(`Serving static files from ${PROD_INDEX_PATH}`);
  }

  app.use("/*", async (req, res, next) => {
    const shop = req.query.shop;

    console.log("THIS IS THE CATCHALL ROUTE")

    // //CHECK TO MAKE SURE SCOPE EXISTS AND ISN'T UNDEFINED, OFFLINE SHOPS?

    const shopValue = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM shop WHERE shop_url=$1`, [
      shop,
    ]);


    if (shopValue?.rows[0]?.scope) {
      ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS[shop] = shopValue.rows[0].scope;
    } else {
      ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS[shop] = undefined;
    }

    // Detect whether we need to reinstall the app, any request from Shopify will
    // include a shop in the query parameters.
    // @ts-ignore
    if (app.get("active-shopify-shops")[shop] === undefined) {
      res.redirect(`/api/auth?shop=${shop}`);
    } else {
      // res.set('X-Shopify-App-Nothing-To-See-Here', '1');
      const fs = await import("fs");

      console.log(`Serving static files from ${DEV_INDEX_PATH}`);
      const fallbackFile = join(
        isProd ? PROD_INDEX_PATH : DEV_INDEX_PATH,
        "index.html"
      );
      res
        .status(200)
        .set("Content-Type", "text/html")
        .send(fs.readFileSync(fallbackFile));
    }
  });

  return { app };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is changing: `app.use(serveStatic(PROD_INDEX_PATH));` to `app.use(serveStatic(PROD_INDEX_PATH, { index: false }));`

It was a bug in the CLI which was resolved [here](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-template-node/issues/932)

Comment: WOW! This caused my app to be rejected several times, while the app installation worked with the /api/auth URL paths, the Installation from the partners dashboard didn't work as the request was sent to the root directory and it resulted in 404!